# Type mismatch or misinterpretation in Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement Entity Framework in C# for moving data from a web service into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. It seemed like everything was coming together swimmingly until I actually tried to run the thing. The model read a varchar(50) field in the database as a string field, which is fine because that's how the same field comes down from the web service. The actual data contained in the field is a 7-digit numeric ID, though, and so when I try this:

```
EntityKey key = new EntityKey("DatabaseEntity.Citations", "ID", idNum);

Citation dbrecord = (Citation)CitationDB.GetObjectByKey(key);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception occurred: The type of the key field 'ID' is expected to be 'System.
String', but the value provided is actually of type 'System.Int32'.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateTypeOfKeyValue(MetadataWorkspace workspace,
EdmMember keyMember, Object keyValue, Boolean isArgumentException,
String argumentName)
   at System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateEntityKey(MetadataWorkspace workspace,
   EntitySet entitySet, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(EntityKey key, Object&
value)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectByKey(EntityKey key)
   at MyLibrary.MyClass.FindSpecificRecordsByState(String username,
String[] states)...
```

I tried changing the type in the model to Int32 and converted the strings in the web service records to Int32 as well, but the assembly stopped compiling at that point and gave me a slew of errors.

Is there anything I can do to get around this problem? The ID field is the primary key and I can't be certain that any of the other fields would work as keys due to unreliable data quality of those fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the type 'string' does not prevent Entity from deciding that it is actually a different type. A coworker suggested adding a Convert.ToString() around the idNum value (which is of type string, not type String), and now it works just fine.